# looking for f(x) in f(x) = a.exp((x-f(x))/b)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, closed-form-expressions

I'm not a math expert, but this problem is really bugging me. Whichever way I turn it, I can't find an expression for $f(x)$ which satisfies
$f(x)=e^{\frac{x-f(x)}{b}}$.

I can also express the problem as $f(x)\cdot e^{\frac{f(x)}{b}}=a\cdot e^{\frac{x}{b}}$

or even solving for $h(x)$ in $\ln(h(x))\cdot h(x)=\frac{a}{b}\cdot e^{a\cdot\frac{x}{b}}$ would do.

The solution exists, as any electrical simulator would show. But I just cannot work out a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be expressed in terms of Lambert W Function which is defined as
$$
x=W(x)e^{W(x)}
$$
Now the problem can turn into:
$$
f(x)=e^{\frac{x-f(x)}{b}} \iff f(x)e^{\frac{f(x)}{b}}=e^{\frac{x}{b}}
$$
Then you get:

> $$
> \frac{1}{b}e^{\frac{x}{b}}=W\left(\frac{f(x)}{b}\right) \iff {f(x)}={b}W^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{b}e^{\frac{x}{b}}\right)
> $$

Comment: See my comment below joro's answer.

Comment: Alas, if you look at what the OP wrote, you'll realize that all you are telling him is that the inverse function has an established name. Unfortunately, that's all there is to tell: $W$ is not elementary.

Comment: @fedja besides an established name, there is a way to compute $W$, which doesn't appear trivial for me.

Comment: @joro You mean something essentially faster than trivial Picard at early steps ($x=\log(y/x)$) combined with standard Newton once you are close enough? Then, of course, it makes sense, but why nobody mentions it anywhere? I mean, Wikipedia mentions that Halley method also gives a decent recursive formula here, but two steps in qubic are the same as 3 in quadratic, so unless you are aiming at extremely high precision, there is no real gain there.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple:

> so:=solve( f(x)-exp(( x - f(x)) /B ),f(x));latex(so);

$$ f(x) =B{\it LambertW} \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {x}{B}}}}{B}^{-1} \right)  $$

And for the title:

> so:=solve( f(x)-A * exp(( x - f(x)) /B ),f(x));latex(so);

$$ f(x) = x- \left( -{\it LambertW} \left( A{{\rm e}^{{\frac {x}{B}}}}{B}^{-1}
 \right) +{\frac {x}{B}} \right) B $$
For Lambert W function [check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertw).

Comment: It would be better to direct the OP to math.stackexchange where the question belongs, rather than encourage the asking of more such questions here where they don't belong.